# Force PhantomJS to have same scrollbar style on different machines?

Tags: phantomjs, scrollbar, cross-platform

I'm writing screenshot-based tests (gemini), using PhantomJS as reference browser.

One thing that makes the tests fail is *different style of scrollbars* (color etc.) on the page.

They differ even on two Windows 10 machines with the the same version of PhantomJS (2.1.1 on Win10 x64).

Is there any way to affect the this style? I.e. make them have same style, or maybe have no style at all.

Comment: I've never seen scrollbars in a PhantomJS screenshot. Are you sure this is not some kind of UI element?

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, I'm absolutely sure I see them for element with `overflow-x: scroll`